# How to create startup disk in ubuntu (Bootable Pendrive)

Tags: ubuntu, bootable

I want to create a bootable pen drive of windows in ubuntu , but i don't have internet for downloading the software like usb disk creator. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you, Try installing the LTS , 12.04 is the Recent LTS Provided by Ubuntu

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man but you can either build your own software or use existing softwares in which case you'll need to download. get [winusb](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/winusb-create-bootable-windows-installer-usb-in-ubuntu-linux/) it's relatively small and easy to use

Comment: I got the winusb, and completed, the bootable disk creation. Shall i directly install the os or should i have to make changes in the OS ?

Comment: if you want to replace the OS, backup any data on your C drive and reinstall, remember to change your Boot priority to FlashDrive from your PC menu. and restart with the flash plugged in.

Comment: I was done with making bootable pen drive itself

Comment: So reboot and install your OS on desired partition

Comment: done, i have rebooted and installed the os

Answer (score 0):

I think this steps works for you.

1. Copy the windows image file on to the desktop and Insert a empty/formated USB stick.
2. Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator.
3. Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app.
4. Click 'Other' to choose the downloaded ISO file.
5. Select the file from desktop which you have copied and click 'Open'.
6. Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk'.
7. That's it! When the process completes, you'll be ready to install windows.